# How to check if it's the first time the user clicks on a link in JSP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have my webapplication structured like this:

Main page with n links and a tabbed structure

Every link opens a tab in the tabbed structure of the main page and with ajax loads the page in the tab

Because every page needs different javascript functions (mainly for the init part) in the complete function of the ajax load I load the .js script and execute it.

Now I have a problem: I need to have a text editor in one of these tabs, so I chose TinyMCE. It needs to be initialized, but only once, otherwise it will crash.
Now I need a way to check how many times the user opened the tab.

I was looking for variables scopes in jsps, and found "Session Scope". I know server side session variables cannot be accessed from clients, but these session scope variables in the jsp are client side, so I thought I would be using a session variable jsp side to count how many times the user clicks on the link.

In the main jsp I put:

```
<c:set var="timesEditorLoaded" value="0" scope="session" />
```

The link which opens the editor is:

```
<a tabindex="22" id="proposte_propostaTesto_a" class="colorbox" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editorPopup?hiddenCallerFormElementId=proposte_propostaTesto&" onClick="incrementEditorVariable();">Apri editor</a>
```

The function incrementEditorVariable() is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function incrementEditorVariable()
{
    alert("incrementEditorVariable: " + timesEditorLoaded);
    timesEditorLoaded = timesEditorLoaded + 1;
}
</script>
```

but in Chrome I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: incrementEditorVariable is not defined
```

If I put the function incrementEditorVariable in an external .js file, how can I access the session variable stored in the jsp?
Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The solution should be pure javascript. Don't get confused by server-side variables.

Comment: As I wrote in the post, I'm talking about client side variables. I'm meaning this --> http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1009

Comment: @Andrea No, you're not talking only about client-side variables--session vars are server-side, as are vars created with a JSP tag. timesEditorLoaded is a server-side variable.

Comment: You have spaces between tag start and tagname. This is invalid syntax.

Comment: I know, I put them myself to post the code here, otherwise the system would not let me enter them.

Comment: Uh, the system will just display it if you format them as code (pad with 4 spaces).

Comment: Jonathan Julian is right. AFAIK TinyMCE is pure javascript - there is absolutely no reason to store such info in session. What will you do when the user will hit refresh button or open another browser tab within the same session?

Comment: I found the solution to the other question, so I don't have to worry about the refresh or another tab, it was a solution posted by an user in the TinyMCE forum and I was trying it. Found it was wrong I don't have to worry about all the possible user behaviours. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a session variable to the MVC architecture, and accomplished this task. I was doing this to try to repair a bug, I accomplished to count the number of times the user clicked on a link to prevent to init n-times a TinyMCE instance, but this didn't solve the problem of the menus staying open.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the onclick event when the user clicks on the button. Seems a little crappy, but can solve everything if the onclick has only one thing to care about.

Comment: I don't understand.. In the onclick I posted I call the javascript function incrementEditorVariable(). I tried also onClick = "${timesEditorLoaded} = incrementEditorVariable();" but with no luck.. Can you explain your comment with more detail on what to modify?

Comment: I mean something like that : btnOnlyOnce.onclick=function(){doIt();btnOnlyOnce.onclick="";} This is a way to prevent having more than one interaction with a control. I used to do it for some JS games and scripts that requires to do something only once.